# Legend for each point in column chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a requirement to display at data set as a pie as well as a column/bar. In case of a pie chart,its possible to show each data point in the legend. Is the same possible in column chart also? Below is what I have tried:

[Fiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/zs92ffu5/9/)

```
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis:{categories:["Jan","Feb","Mar"]},
    plotOptions: {

        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true
        }
    },
    series: [{data:[{name:'Jan',y:20},{name:'Feb',y:24},{name:'Mar',y:35}],showInLegend:true}]
            });
```

I wish to show 'Jan', 'Feb' and 'Mar' in the legend. Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
 for  category name in legends ,see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/md2zk/110)

If you want to show value in legend you have to include a plugin for that see [this link](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2759455-show-value-in-legend)
 and its [working fiddle with value in legends here](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/DVvdZ/)

If you want to show value on top of columns you need to use datalables as like below code

```
 plotOptions: {

        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
                dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'black', //choose your own color whatever you want
            style: {
                textShadow: '0 0 3px black' //if you need text shadow
            }
        } 
        }
    }
```

see [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/zs92ffu5/10/)

Comment: this is not what I am looking for. Actually in the link which I have posted I want 'Jan','Feb' and 'Mar' in the legend instead of Series 1. If the chart type is 'pie', all points are shown in the legend. I want the same behavior in 'column' chart as well.

Comment: did you seen the link I shared in starting of answer?

Comment: @Viji got it, I think you need something like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/md2zk/110/ Check it and reply . it has category name in legends

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried the same solution by din;t have the plot options. http://jsfiddle.net/t3gtsmto/8/ .

Comment: you can skip plotOption part if you don't want to customize there

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks a lot.